# Android: Extending a custom abstract Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, abstract-class

I created an abstract Activity which extends the android.app.Activity. Then I created an activity extending my abstract one. [1]

Everything is fine with ant, but eclipse showed an error in the manifest saying that my activiy did not exists, so I regenerate the class files and the error in the manifest is gone. But now eclipse shows an error at the root of my project and don't want to compile.

I precise that the activity is working fine in a device builded with ant. I tried to "Fix Project Properties" as well. I can't declare the abstract activity because of it's abstract.

Anybody already saw this bug ?

Thanks

[1] Here is a little schematic

android.app.Activity ->  abstract ActivityNet -> MyActivity

Comment: There is no problem with that setup.  Can you show your manifest?  Did you try restarting eclipse, rebuilding/recreating project, etc?  Sometimes eclipse gets confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common bug/behaviour of Eclipse.

To eliminate it click on the "Problems" icon (right bottom corner but it depends on your prospective)

Right click on the error line and then delete it.

The error should be gone away now